# How do I set the fill character for displaying numbers (Objective C)

Tags: iphone, cocoa, printf, stringwithformat

I'm trying to format a string to give me 2 characters for a number, no matter what its value. Right now, I have

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%2d:%2d",h,m,s)];
```

and for the values 1, 2, 3, the output is

```
 1: 2: 3
```

How do I change the spaces to 0's ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done the same as C's printf (see man 3 printf):

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",h,m,s];`

(By the way, if you're trying to format dates or times, I'd suggest looking at [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/).)